# Titanium youtube debug request

Tags: youtube, titanium

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Qg6k.png

```html
//Application Window Component Constructor
function hsVideoWindow(videoID) {
 Ti.include('/ui/include/config.js');
 var IMG_BASE = '/images/';
  
 //alert(videoID);
 //construct UI
 var self = Ti.UI.createWindow({
  viewName: 'videoWindow',
  title: 'VIDEO',
  navBarHidden:false,
  layout:'vertical',
  backgroundImage:backgroundImage,
  zIndex: 0
 });

 
 var myVideoID = ('p4g9_R6cg7s');
 var webView = Ti.UI.createWebView({
    url: 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + myVideoID + '?autoplay=1&autohide=1&cc_load_policy=0&color=white&controls=0&fs=0&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0',
    enableZoomControls: false,
    scalesPageToFit: false,
    scrollsToTop: false,
    showScrollbars: false
});


self.add(webView);

self.open();
 
 return self;
}

//make constructor function the public component interface
module.exports = hsVideoWindow;
```

Can anyone help me to fix this ?

It is able to display only the youtube video's thumbnail. However it is unable to stream the video within the webview.

Comment: Please do **not** put a screenshot of code, embed [the code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in text format...

Comment: sorry, im not use to ask questions in this website @bufh ;( ediited thanks

Comment: That's better, thank you.